# Healthcheck inheritance in docker compose with extends attribute

Tags: docker, deployment, continuous-integration, devops

In docker compose file when I use the `extends` attribute does it use/inherit the `healthcheck` definition from the extended service or do I have to define a separate one?

```
backend:
    image: docker-image
    ports:
        - 1234:1234
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD", "curl", "localhost:1234/healthcheck" ]
        interval: 2s
        retries: 10
        start_period: 10s
        timeout: 10s

backend-2:
    extends:
        service: backend
    depends_on:
        - mongodb
    healthcheck: # is that healthcheck part needed here or could it be skipped?
        test: [ "CMD", "curl", "localhost:1234/healthcheck" ]
        interval: 5s
        retries: 15
        start_period: 15s
        timeout: 5s
```

Thanks!